# consistent axis scale in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using matlab for plotting scatter data. I want that the figure be in the range of [0 68] for X and [0 100] for Y, but when I use the following command, the X and Y axis are not consistent. For example, I expect the vertical axis to be longer than horizontal, while matlab give me something else. Have I missed something in the figure setting?

```
figure, axis([0 68 0 100]); box off , scatter(y,x,100,val,'filled'); box on;
```

[image]

Comment: `axis equal` might help.

Comment: actually I don't want to have an equal axis and it does not work!

Comment: Take a look at [this part of the Matlab documentation, which explains how to control aspect ratios](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-axis-parameters.html#f6-20302).

Comment: @Nicole I had prepared an answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647744/using-matlab-interpolation-for-scattered-data), which was deleted before I submitted my answer. If you want still some feedback, you can undelete the question and I will submit my answer.

Comment: @chappjc: Thanks a lot for your time and pursuing for helping. Actually I found the answer of my question in somewhere else and that is why I deleted the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a matter of the order of commands.

```
x = 1:60;
y = 1/3.*x;

plot(x,y)
grid on
axis([0 60 0 20])
axis equal
```

will return

[image]

what you don't want, as it screws up your limits.

So rather use:

```
axis equal
axis([0 60 0 20])
```

and it is alright:

[image]